# Generate arrays with options from field values

Tags: jquery, arrays

Is there a way to produce an array from a series of spans containing input fields in the format of:

```
[[1,100],[2,200],[3,300],[4,400]]
```

HTML:

```
<div id="arrays">
<span>
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="100">
</span>
<span>
<input type="text" value="2">
<input type="text" value="200">
</span>
<span>
<input type="text" value="3">
<input type="text" value="300">
</span>
</div>
```

I've tackled it like this without success:

```
str = [];
$('#arrays').children("span").find('input').each(function(index) {
str[index] = $(this).val();
});

var string = [ str ];
```

The array will then be passed to jqPlot as follows:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [string]);
```

Without generating an array, the code would look like this (example):

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[[1,100],[2,200],[3,300]]]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
str = [];


  $('#arrays span').each(function(){
    var value1 = $(this).find('input['input:first']')val();
    var value2 =  $(this).find('input['input:last']')val();
     var r = [value1 ,value2 ];
    str .push(r);

   });
```

Comment: thank you I've just tried it, but it's not fetching the values of the fields, does it need .val() ?

Comment: This works:
`str = [];
  $('#tochart span').each(function(){
      var value1 = $(this).find('input:first').val();
      var value2 =  $(this).find('input:last').val();
     var r = [value1 ,value2 ];
    str .push(r);

   });`